# Remote Partitioning : Spring batch with Kafka as middle wear

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

Can someone help with some of the queries with remote partitioning with Kafka as middle wear.

1. In master application with partition class return a map of   Map<String, ExecutionContext> , which contains complete information of what workers will do, but how this information is passed to workers as I can see Kafka message contains very limited information "
   `{"stepExecutionId":442,"stepName":"workerStep","jobExecutionId":121}"`
2. When Kafka is used as middle wear, How many partitions we should keep in Kafka (Best practice) number of Kafka partitions should be equal to the number of worker nodes.Each worker reading data from one Kafka topic.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. The worker retrieves the information from the Database.
2. You need at least as many partitions as there are workers; generally, it's best to over-provision the partitions, so you can scale out the workers later without having to change anything in the broker.

Comment: Thanks  Gary
1. Is it like without a shared job repository between remote machines, remote partitioning can not be implemented or there is some configurable way where I can keep the job repository of machines isolated and run Remote partitioning.(Master and worker communicates only through Kafka and worker do not  get information from common job repository)                 
2. In the case where the job repository is a must and the worker retrieves information from the database (job repository), Kafka message contains the primary key information of record which needs to be queried?

Comment: No; that is not possible; the remote workers must access the same `JobRepository` as the partitioner. As well as returning the execution result, the remote workers update that state in the DB.